# WebMethod never be called in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery to call C# code behind methods. Here is my ascx file code:

**ASPX**

```
<div class="dnnFormItem">
<asp:LinkButton id="cmdLogin" resourcekey="cmdLogin" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" text="Login" runat="server" />
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=cmdLogin.ClientID %>').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Login.ascx/ServerSideMethod",
            data: "{sendData: '" + ID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) { 
                alert("successful!" + result.d); 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod()
{
    return String.Format("Hello");
}
```

Please help me out to solve this. My WebMethod function in C# is never be called.

Answer (score 0):

your ServerSideMethod() is expecting a parameter sendData. have you tried using an aspx page or an asmx rather than an ascx

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a parameter but the web method doesn't take any parameters, so is likely throwing an exception. Use the error function to find this for sure. This can be done similar to your success callback. Information about that can be found in the Jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Hi I also tried to catch an error. And it is for sure that webmethod is not calling.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your initial post and thought the method was in the aspx rather than the ascx. As far as I am aware it is not possible to call web methods within a user control. Is there a specific reason as to why the method cannot be placed inside the aspx or refactored to call an asmx service?

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, if you carry on down the page method route, don't forget to set EnablePageMethods to true for your script manager , if you haven't done so already!

Answer (score 0):

for `data: "{sendData: '" + ID + "'}",`

check if `ID` really exist??? if if you want to really pass the parameter to `ServerSideMethod` else remove this line in case you are not passing this parameter to `ServerSideMethod`.

and change WebMethod,pass parameter `sendData`

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string ServerSideMethod(string sendData)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`url: "Login.ascx/ServerSideMethod"`

You'll have to move your "service" to an `asmx` (or `aspx`, `ashx`) file - WebMethods can't be in UserControls..

I've seen some "workarounds" but *IMHO*, they're not really workarounds per se...or should I say "hacky" and ends up being more convoluted than just going `asmx`

Hth...